# How to extend the functionality of eosio.token?

Tags: smart-contract, tokens

I want to create an EOSIO token with additional functionality. For example, I want users to be able to claim() an additional token per day (since e.g. account creation date).

Should I create a new contract (e.g. ubi.cpp/ubi.hpp) and use the eosio.token source code as a template (i.e. derive my token class from contract, just like the eosio.token class does), or should I try to have e.g. an "ubi" class that subclasses "eosio.token" instead of "contract?"

I want the custom token to be compatible with all wallets and such, and work everywhere a vanilla eosio.token is expected.

I can't seem to find any tutorial on custom tokens that support additional actions. All token creation tutorials I can find are based on just using the standard eosio.token contract and invoking create/issue/etc to manipulate table entries.

Answer (score 2):

Reddit user xxqsgg has answered my question over there: https://www.reddit.com/r/EOSDev/comments/ap2or0/how_to_extend_the_functionality_of_eosiotoken/

Basically, the correct way to do it on EOSIO is the following:

1. Create an account for the custom token that is going to be created, and deploy the standard eosio.token contract there;
2. Write a new contract that contains all the extra functionality, and deploy that to a separate account.

The idea is that contract/account #2 above has all the extra actions that users can invoke (e.g. claim() the tokens defined and stored at the #1 account with your standard eosio.contract deployment). Account #2 will probably have the proper permission to manipulate Account #1, i.e. issue extra tokens, etc.